# Generate select options from a numeric value

Tags: angular, select, typescript

I am trying to generate the dropdown based on a variable .

Say if the totalqty is 5, i need to generate the dropdown options as 1,2,3,4,5.

i have done it with angular1, but it does not work for me

```
   <select>
       <option *ngFor="let i of arr(totalqty).fill(1)">{{i}}</option>
   </select>
```

Comment: Whats wrong to do it through typescript?

Comment: @NikhilShah what do you mean

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't do it directly in your template.

Do it in your component instead, see my working demo: https://plnkr.co/edit/6Ma2tkfSKfpzxQmiNQl1?p=preview

There are 2 ways:

- generate an array
- using a pipe

```js
@Pipe({ name: 'createArrayOfValues' })
export class CreateArrayOfValuesPipe implements PipeTranfsform {
  public transform(qty: number): number[] {
    if (!qty || isNaN(qty)) return [];
    return new Array(qty).fill(0).map((v, i) => i + 1);
  }
}

@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  template: `
    <div>
      <h2>Hello {{name}}</h2>
    </div>
    <select>
      <option *ngFor="let i of values">{{i}}</option>
    </select>
    <select>
      <option *ngFor="let i of zerovalues; let idx = index;">{{idx + 1}}</option>
    </select>
    <select>
      <option *ngFor="let i of 5 | createArrayOfValues">{{i}}</option>
    </select>
  `,
})
export class App {
  name:string;
  values = [];
  zerovalues = [];

  constructor() {
    this.name = 'Angular2'
    this.updateValues(5);
  }

  updateValues(qty: number) {
    this.values = new Array(qty).fill(0).map((v, i) => i + 1);
    this.zerovalues = new Array(qty).fill(0);
  }
}
```